# Looping to search string variables with local list

Tags: string, loops, stata

I am working with a very long list of commodity names (var1). I would like to extract information from this list by creating a second variable (var2) that is equal to 1 if var1 contains certain keywords.

I was using the following code:

```
g soy = strpos(productsproduced, "Soybeans, ") | strpos(productsproduced, "Soybean, ")   | strpos(productsproduced, "soybeans, ")| strpos(productsproduced, "soybean, ") | productsproduced == "Soybeans"
```

The list is much longer, given that the data was not properly coded, and each name appears in many different ways (as the excerpt in the code sample shows).

I believe that it would be much easier to work with a list (easier to look through the list certainly, and see if I am missing anything, etc.)

Unfortunately, it has been a while since I have worked with loops, but I was thinking something of the sort:

```
local mylist Soybean soybean Soybeans soybeans Soybeans, soybeans,
forval i = mylist {
g soy = strpos(var1, "`i'")
}
```

This doesn't quite work, but I am not sure how to code it. One definite issue is that Stata would not know in this case whether I would like it to use the or operator (yes, I would) or the and operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spirit is evident; the details need various fixes.

```
local mywords Soybean soybean Soybeans soybeans Soybeans, soybeans,
gen soy = 0 
foreach w of local mywords {
   replace soy = soy | strpos(var1, "`w'")
}
```

What's crucial is that you need `replace` inside the loop; otherwise the loop will fail second time round on a `generate` as the variable already exists.

In fact this example reduces to

```
gen soy = strpos(var1, "oybean") > 0
```

on the assumption that `oybean` wouldn't match anything not wanted.

Standardising to lower case is often helpful

```
local mywords soybean soybeans soybeans, 
gen soy = 0 
foreach w of local mywords {
   replace soy = soy | strpos(lower(var1), "`w'")
}
```

Comment: Nick Cox: Thank you for your help. This works perfectly and will save a lot of time. I seem not able to tag, but do you have any pointers in case I would like to avoid sections of strings? As you said, it reduces to "gen soy = strpos(var1, "oybean") > 0 assuming that oybean doesn't match anything that I don't want included. What if string "fancy soybeans" is not of interest to me but a string that says "fancy soybeans and soybeans" is of interest (because of the "normal" soybeans)?

Comment: One approach is to see what is left if you remove `fancy soybeans` from the string. You don't have to change the variable, just work on `subinstr(var1, "fancy soybeans", "", .)`.